# JSON Deserialize - Convert common types of objects into list

Tags: c#, json, .net, api, deserialization

I have the below JSON coming from API

```
{
  "rates": {
    "EURGBP": {
      "rate": 0.871625,
      "timestamp": 1619193484
    },
    "USDJPY": {
      "rate": 107.939463,
      "timestamp": 1619193484
    }
  }
}
```

I want to create classes to deserialize this JSON. If I do JSON to C# conversion I get the below C# classes:

```
public class Rates
{
    public EURGBP EURGBP { get; set; }
    public USDJPY USDJPY { get; set; }
}

public class EURGBP
{
    public double rate { get; set; }
    public int timestamp { get; set; }
}

public class USDJPY
{
    public double rate { get; set; }
    public int timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is there might be more objects coming in `rates` object. Like

```
"NZDUSD": {
    "rate": 0.718962,
    "timestamp": 1619198884
}
```

In this case I won't be having a class `NZDUSD` to deserialize the new object.

So can I have a generic class using which I can deserialize the objects under `rates` since they will be having the common properties?

OR

Can I convert those objects under `rates` into `List` or `Dictionary` while or after deserializing?

Comment: If only the api returned them in an array...

Comment: You need to [deserialize into a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net).

Comment: Is `rates` a collection of records? Do class names like `EURGBP` have some internal structure, perhaps a relation from Euros to British pounds or something? Is `rate` something financial, like an exchange rate? Is `timestamp` a continuous number, like a time of day? If any of those statements are true, there are problems with both your JSON and your classes. However, to give you better answers we would need to know a lot more about your JSON and what you will be using it for.

Answer (score 3):

You could create an object model like this using a dictionary:

```
        public class Result
        {
            public IDictionary<string, Rate> Rates { get; set; }
        }

        public class Rate
        {
            public double rate { get; set; }
            public int timestamp { get; set; }
        }
```

and then deserialize using Newtonsoft:

```
var values = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

> So can I have a generic class using which I can deserialize the objects under rates since they will be having the common properties?

There are a few different way's you can accomplish this, one of which was already offered by [Connell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67235108/1797425). Another way you can do this is by creating your own `JsonConverter`. Below I will show you how you can do this.

-Create a new class called: `CurrencyConverter` make sure it's like below:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using Newtonsoft.Json;
  using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
  
  public class CurrencyConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => typeof(List<Rate>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            List<Rate> rates = new List<Rate>();

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
            {
                JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
                IEnumerable<JToken> tokenChildren = token.Root.First?.First?.Children();
                foreach (JToken child in tokenChildren)
                {
                    double dblRate = GetValue(child.First, "rate", 0d);
                    int intTimeStamp = GetValue(child.First, "timestamp", 0);
                    rates.Add(new Rate() { RateName = ((JProperty)child).Name, rate = dblRate, Timestamp = intTimeStamp });
                }
            }

            return rates;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public T GetValue<T>(JToken jToken, string key, T defaultValue = default(T))
        {
            dynamic ret = jToken[key];
            if (ret == null) return defaultValue;
            if (ret is JObject) return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(ret.ToString());
            return (T)ret;
        }
    }
```

-Next create a new class called `Rate`:

```
public class Rate
{
    public string RateName { get; set; }
    public double rate { get; set; }
    public int Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

-Finally deserialize your `json`:

```
 JsonSerializerSettings jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
 jsonSerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new CurrencyConverter());
 var jsonOutput = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Rate>>(json, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

Using the `json` you provided, I got back a list that had two `Rate` objects.